# condition for input field and checkbox

Tags: javascript, class, checkbox, input-field, prop

how can i create a condition for multiple checkbox!

```
Input Field ID =" INsrvOtr "

CheckBox ID = "INsrv"
```

let's say that the that the user has two options,either put a value on the input field or choose any value from the checkbox but he can only choose "ONE" of the two options

Checkbox:

```
 <input id="INsrv" name="INopt" type="checkbox" value="1" />1<br>
```

Input field:

```
<input id="OUTsrvOtr" name="OUToptOtr" type="text" value="" onblur="valINP()"/><br><br>
```

if the user inputs a value in the input field this will happen

if "input field" is not empty, class of all the "checkbox" will not contain a value.

```
<script>
function valINP(){
    $("#INsrv1").prop('class','text')
    $("#INsrvOtr").prop('class','validate[required] text-input text')
    }
}
</script>
```

or if the user chooses to check the checkbox this will happen

and if the "checkbox" is not selected,class of "input field" will not contain a value.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='INopt']").click(function() {
    $("#INsrv1").prop('class','validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox text')
    $("#INsrvOtr").prop('class','text')
    });
});
</script>
```

or if both is not selected

the script will contain this two:

```
 $("#INsrv").prop('class','validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox text')
 $("#INsrvOtr").prop('class','validate[required] text-input text')
```

Comment: You didn't say what libraries you're using, what exactly do you want to achieve, and what exactly is the problem that you're getting. I don't expect many answers to your question unless you add more details and real code examples with HTML that you're working on, preferably using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/).

Answer (score 0):

try optimize your code, some useful optimization for selecting controls 
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ or http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/

using some thing like

$("#id|="INsrv"]').prop('class','')

sorry if the syntax goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Use this for INsrv([0-9]+)
$('[id^="INsrv"][id!="INsrvOtr"]').each(function() {

});

// Or if you only want to call `prop`
$('[id^="INsrv"][id!="INsrvOtr"]').prop('yourprop', '');
```

Then you can just call `$('#INsrvOtr')` separately.

Comment: INsrv([0-9]+) not working is this correct ?   $("#INsrv([0-9]+)").prop('class','')

Comment: No. Use the code below it. That was a comment, and I was using a regular expression to show what it would be matching.